# Format of PHP Array (Column / Row Structure)

Tags: php, arrays, fgetcsv

I have 15 countries, for each country there are a set amount of 20 points. For each point there is a different value per country

Example

The UK in Price Point 1 has a Price Value of 1.3

The US in Price Point 1 has a Price Value of 1.5

And so on,

Should I go with the approach like this or is there a better way to do this.

I want to firstly put this into a CSV then use fgetcsv to convert it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => US
            [price_point] => 1
            [price_value] => 1.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => UK
            [price_point] => 1
            [price_value] => 1.3
        )
)
```

Comment: it's perfect approach.

Comment: If going into a CSV this is the ideal. Row is the array position, those 3 attributes are column headers

Comment: Thanks, however surely with this approach the array size will be 300, I thought there might be a simple way of doing it as there is only 20 fixed points for price point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide that in your code-treasue-box;

```
$array = 'what you have above';
//re-index
$array = array_values($array);
//keep keys ordered
ksort($array[0]);
//make the header
$table ="<table><tr><th>".implode("</th><th>",array_keys($array[0]))."</th></td>";
//iterate 
foreach($array as $arr){
    ksort($arr);//sort 
    $table .= "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>",$arr)."</td></tr>";
}

print $table."</table>";
```

This can also updated for use with `fwrite` and so on.

( **I missed a little the topic here, but can be handy ;-)** )

Have a nice day